# Issue In Sql Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below sql query  When i execute it with some values in where condition it displays data and if i place values in [Sp_GrnValuationReportV1]--1,'GR140000001','GR140000009','2014-10-11','2014-12-25' it is display no data.Please help me to solve the issue.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_GrnValuationReportV1] --1,'GR140000001','GR140000009','2014-10-11','2014-12-25'
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @i_LocationID int,
    @i_GrnStartNo varchar,
    @i_GrnEndNo varchar,
    @d_StartDate DATE,
    @d_EndDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT DISTINCT GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteNo,GRN.LocationID,GRN.CreatedOn,PO.PurchaseOrderNo,V.VendorName,
    GRN.SupplierInvoiceNo,GRN.SupplierInvoiceDate,SR.LRNO,T.TransporterName,
CASE
    WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) OVER(partition BY GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1 
    THEN Isnull(( GRND.FreightCharges ), 0.00)
    ELSE Isnull(( OEC.FreightCharges ), 0.00)
END FreightCharge,CASE
    WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) OVER(partition BY GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1 
    THEN Isnull(( GRND.LoadingCost + GRND.UnloadingCost ), 0.00)
    ELSE Isnull(( OEC.LoadingCost + OEC.UnloadingCost ), 0.00)
END LoadingandUnloadingcharges ,
    P.ProductCode,P.ProductName,GRND.ReceivedQuantity,GRND.RejectedQuantity,GRND.AcceptedQuantity,
    GRND.UnitPrice AS BasicRate,ISNULL( (GRND.UnitPrice*GRND.ReceivedQuantity),0.00) BasicValue,GRND.VAT,CASE
    WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) OVER(partition BY GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1 
    THEN Isnull(( GRND.FreightCharges ), 0.00)
    ELSE Isnull(( OEC.FreightCharges ), 0.00)
END FreightApportioned,
    CASE
    WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) OVER(partition BY GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1 
    THEN Isnull(( GRND.LoadingCost + GRND.UnloadingCost ), 0.00)
    ELSE Isnull(( OEC.LoadingCost + OEC.UnloadingCost ), 0.00)
END LoadingandUnloadingApportioned,ISNULL((GRND.UnitPrice+OEC.FreightCharges+OEC.LoadingCost+OEC.UnloadingCost),0.00)AS TotalCost           
    FROM GoodsReceivedNoteDetail GRND
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GoodsReceivedNote GRN ON GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteID=GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PurchaseOrder PO ON PO.PurchaseOrderID=GRN.PurchaseOrderID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendor V ON V.VendorID=PO.VendorID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SecurityRegister SR ON SR.SecurityRegisterID=GRN.SecurityRegisterID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Transporter T ON T.TransporterID=SR.TransporterID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OtherExpenseCost OEC ON OEC.GoodsReceivedNoteID=GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Product P ON P.ProductID=GRND.ProductID
    --WHERE   GRN.LocationID=@i_LocationID AND GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteNo>=@i_GrnStartNo AND GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteNo<=@i_GrnEndNo or GRN.CreatedOn>=@d_StartDate AND GRN.CreatedOn<=@d_EndDate
    WHERE  CAST( GRND.CreatedOn AS DATE)>=@d_StartDate AND  GRN.LocationID=1 AND CAST( GRND.CreatedOn AS DATE) <=@d_EndDate  AND GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteNo>=  @i_GrnStartNo AND GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteNo <=@i_GrnEndNo
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the problem in the big queries follow this instructions

1. Copy and Paste the body of stored proc to a new query window
2. change the columns in select to `*`. I mean change your query to `select * from`
3. declare the parameters at the top of query and set the values to them
4. Start commenting the joins and run the query to see which one makes it to return no rows. you might need to comment the corresponding conditions in where statement.

I hope this helps you

Comment: Issue has been Solved it is due varchar i have not mentioned the size of varchar Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mention The Size of varchar

```
@i_GrnStartNo varchar(50),
    @i_GrnEndNo varchar(50),
```